# Laravel 5 custom module routes not working

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

I'm creating my custom modules for my projects to be able to add some features to a project or another depending of the requeriments.

My issue is with the routes, I load the routes in a `ModuleServiceProvider` loaded in app.php:

```
include __DIR__.'/../../modules/canae/Http/routes.php';
```

I checked that this works with an echo inside that file. The routes.php file contains the following code:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::controller('dogs', 'Canae\Http\Controllers\Admin\DogController');
});
```

I also checked that Laravel can find the Controller, the problem is that it's unable to execute the code inside it.

Here's the code I have inside DogController:

```
<?php namespace Canae\Http\Controllers\Admin;

class DogController extends \Origin\Http\Controllers\Controller {
    public function getIndex() {
        echo "Hello!";die();
    }
}
```

And the error is `Controller method not found.`

If I modify the `extends` below to `Origin\Http\Controllers\Controller` (removing the first `\`) I get the following error: `Class 'Canae\Http\Controllers\Admin\Origin\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found` so my conclusion is that the code inside this controller is executing, at least reading from Laravel.

Also I'm trying to achieve the Index function with this route `http://localhost/canae/public/admin/dogs/index`.

This is the tail result of executing `php artisan route:list`:

```
|        | GET|HEAD                       | admin/dogs/index/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}                       |        | Canae\Http\Controllers\Admin\DogController@getIndex                | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | admin/dogs                                                                    |        | Canae\Http\Controllers\Admin\DogController@getIndex                | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE | admin/dogs/{_missing}                                                         |        | Canae\Http\Controllers\Admin\DogController@missingMethod           | auth       |
+--------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Tell me if you need more information. And thanks for your time.

Comment: Try it with an explicit route for testing: `Route::get('test', 'Canae\Http\Controllers\Admin\DogController@getIndex')` and go to `http://localhost/canae/public/admin/test`

Comment: @lukasgeiter same error doing that :(

Comment: Try running `php artisan route:clear` quickly to be sure nothing is cached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it moving the line inside `providers` that loads this routes to the first item of the `providers` array, even before the application ones. Don't know why, but now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

In light of the docs at: http://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers

Have you tried using the "use" statement? Your code would then look like:

```
<?php 

namespace Canae\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Canae\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class DogController extends Controller {
    public function getIndex() {
        echo "Hello!";die();
    }
}
```

I'm also not sure why your namespace is "Canae\Http\Controllers\Admin" as the example shows "App\Http\Controllers" only. I'm not familiar with the specific structure of your project, but removing the "\Admin" might also help.

Comment: Yes, I also tried that, app directory has the namespace Origin, and modules/canae has the namespace Canae, just for create a modular app. I solved the problem as I answered in this thread, don't know why but it works. Thanks :)